# Shade smooth on flat surfaces?

Tags: modeling, smooth

I have this beveled rectangular prism here and I want it to be shaded smooth so that the bezels are smooth. But it causes the long flat faces to look weird, like they aren't flat. How can I make just the edges to the flat face smooth, and not have the entire face be smooth?

[image]

Comment: In what way do the faces "look weird"? Have you checked Auto Smooth on the Normals tab or used the Shade Auto Smooth option if you're using a recent Blender version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the *Weighted Normal* modifier, it will limit the smooth shading to the small faces and won't try to smooth the large ones. Note that you need to enable the *Auto Smooth* option to make it work:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed, @moonboots!